# Keyboard Layout Changing Issues

Tags: keyboard, 15.10, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I'm on ubuntu 15.10 and I have two keyboard layouts: Persian and English(UK).

When I try to switch between these two if I keep holding the shift (I use <kbd>R ALT</kbd> + <kbd>R Shift</kbd> shortcut to switch ) it will still write in the layout I was on while it wasn't like this on Windows and once I pressed <kbd>R Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R Shift</kbd> it would change the layout.

Example:

With holding shift after pressing shortcut -> `HelLO`

Leaving shift after pressing shortcut and then starting to type: `Helمو`

---

Believe me it's so annoying and I think it can be resolved but donno how!

Comment: Have you tried to change to the default shortcut <Super>+<Space>?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson well actually I've customised the shortcut key to be `R ALT + R SHIFT` just like windows because I have to switch between Ubuntu and Windows all the time for some reasons and I will get confused if they don't have the same shortcuts, etc.

Comment: Yeah, but I mentioned it because some shortcuts simply don't work since they conflict with other functions. Can't tell if it would be possible to make the one you prefer work.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Thanks anyway. I will try another shortcut to see if it works or not and will let you know. :)

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Thank you Gunnar, it works perfectly. I tried to change the shortcut key and it works perfectly now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Noticed that I was only using `Switch to next source using:` and `Switch to previous source using:` was empty. I tried reassigning the same shortcut key again and it works perfectly now thanks to @GunnarHjalmarsson suggestion in the comments above.

Comment: Great that you sorted it out. :)